# URL Change in Codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

I have a URL

```
http://localhost/himalaya/webmanager/recentUpdate/index/edit-recent-update-1
```

but I want it to make the URL like this:

```
http://localhost/himalaya/webmanager/recentUpdate/edit-recent-update-1.
```

The controller name is `recentUpdate` and method name is `index`. My question is how can I remove `index` method name from URL in codeigniter framework?

Comment: i have followed your instruction but index method is not hiding from url

Comment: you can use also routing for this. see CI Routing

Comment: i have used this routing $route['webmanager/recentUpdate/index/(:any)'] = 'webmanager/recentUpdate/$1'; but not hidding index method name

Comment: cause you are showing this CI $route['new route'] = old route

Comment: so what i have to write for routing controller name recentUpdate and parameter is passing through index method.

Comment: so what i have to write for routing controller name recentUpdate and parameter is passing through index method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi First you just read the what is index.php work in codeigniter.
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

For remove the index then you write routing rule in .htaccess file.
above the application folder

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project_name/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

add .htaccess file in your project.

Add code in it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```